# delete keys from a nested object from an array of keys

Tags: javascript

I have a very large array of objects that I need the keys remove from. I can't seem to get my head around how to make this happen with list of keys.

https://jsfiddle.net/rgfx_fiddle/cvoz7ygm/15/

```js
const sections = [
            {
                municipality: "Monte De Oca",
                office: "Oficina de la Mujer"
            },
            {
                case_number: "MDO-ABCDEFG",
                identification: "Cédula",
                id_number: "123456789"
            }
];
    
const removeThis = [
    "municipality",
    "id_number"
]


function filter(data) {
  for(var i in data){
    if(removeThis.indexOf(i) != -1){
       delete data[i]; 
    }
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(filter(sections));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to iterate the objects in `sections`, with a `forEach` over the keys in `removeThis` to delete them from each object:

```js
const sections = [{
    municipality: "Monte De Oca",
    office: "Oficina de la Mujer"
  },
  {
    case_number: "MDO-ABCDEFG",
    identification: "Cédula",
    id_number: "123456789"
  }
];

const removeThis = [
  "municipality",
  "id_number"
]

sections.forEach(obj => {
  removeThis.forEach(k => delete obj[k])
  return obj
})

console.log(sections)
```

If you don't want to mutate your original objects, you can build new ones using a combination of `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`, filtering out the keys from `removeThis`:

```js
const sections = [{
    municipality: "Monte De Oca",
    office: "Oficina de la Mujer"
  },
  {
    case_number: "MDO-ABCDEFG",
    identification: "Cédula",
    id_number: "123456789"
  }
];

const removeThis = [
  "municipality",
  "id_number"
]

const result = sections.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, _]) => !removeThis.includes(k))
  )
)

console.log(result)
console.log(sections)
```